# Sorting 1 million queries

Tags: algorithm

```
I have 1 million queries on disk to sort, my local memory/cache can store
up to 1 thousand queries, how can I perform sort?
```

This is a google interview question. Can someone help me find the answer?

Comment: Sort by what?  What have you considered so far?  Research different sorts, esp. merge sort.

Comment: related: [How would you sort 1 million 32-bit integers in 2MB of RAM?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/134158/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You load 1000 queries in memory and sort them using **quicksort**, writing them to a file. In the end you'll have 1000 such files.

You then go on to merging the files using, you guessed it, **mergesort**.

That's how I'd do it. By no means the most optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

[External merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting#External_merge_sort) can be employed to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Get more memory. A query is not that big. It's a question that tests whether you can think outside the box.

Answer (score 1):

I am lazy: Read all queries (1,000 each), dump them in a database, then `SELECT ORDER BY anything`. If it is Google asking, they'll have databases anyway...