# How can I pass the line I'm iterating over into a sort/sorted function in a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, for-loop, parameters, key

I'm trying to loop over a number of log-files and need to sort file entries (lines) across all files being looped

This is what I'm doing:

```
import glob

f = glob.glob('logs/')
for line in sorted(fileinput.input(f), key=stringsplit(line)):
  print line
```

So, I'm opening all files and then want to use the stringsplit function (which extracts a date from the file entry) as sorting criteria.

Problem is, doing this gives me an error saying:

```
name 'line' is not defined
```

**Question:**
Is it not possible to pass the `line` being loop-ed as parameter into a sorting function? How can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: try `key=lambda line: stringsplit(line)`. The sorting is done before you start iterating in the for-loop.

Comment: ah. Thanks. 1st week with Python... don you want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `key=lambda line: stringsplit(line)`.

The sorting is done before you start iterating in the for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

The `key` keyword must be a callable. It is called for *every* entry in the input sequence.

A `lambda` is an easy way to create such a callable:

```
sorted(..., key=lambda line: stringsplit(line))
```

I would be *extremely* wary of sorting the output of `fileinput` with many, large files though. `sorted()` *must* read *all* lines into memory to be able to sort them. If your files are many and / or large, you'll use up all memory, eventually leading to a `MemoryError` exception.

Use a different method to pre-sort your logs first. You can use a the UNIX tool `sort`, or use a [external sorting technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465154/sorting-text-file-by-using-python/14465236#14465236) instead.

If your input files are already sorted, you can merge them using the same key:

```
import operator

def mergeiter(*iterables, **kwargs):
    """Given a set of sorted iterables, yield the next value in merged order"""
    iterables = [iter(it) for it in iterables]
    iterables = {i: [next(it), i, it] for i, it in enumerate(iterables)}
    if 'key' not in kwargs:
        key = operator.itemgetter(0)
    else:
        key = lambda item, key=kwargs['key']: key(item[0])

    while True:
        value, i, it = min(iterables.values(), key=key)
        yield value
        try:
            iterables[i][0] = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            del iterables[i]
            if not iterables:
                raise
```

then pass in your *open* file objects:

```
files = [open(f) for f in glob.glob('logs/*')]
for line in mergeiter(*files, key=lambda line: stringsplit(line)):
    # lines are looped over in merged order.
```

but you need to make *certain* that the `stringsplit()` function returns values as they are ordered in the input log files.

Comment: good tip. I was going to check how much lines my memory can swallow ... :-)

Comment: mh. I need to sort by date-time. Seperate files are sorted by date-time, but I can only do a global sort to get items A-Z across all files, so merging sorted files won't help, will it?

Comment: @frequent: if your separate files are already sorted on date, then you can merge them. See the question I linked to, you could adapt the technique shown there to merge the files.

Comment: @frequent: Updated my answer with an adaptation of my `mergeiter()` function.

Comment: the lines are strings which include dates like '14/Nov/2012:13:12:23', stringsplit extracts the this string and converts it to sortable `2012-11-14:13:12:23`. Let's see if this works

Comment: @frequent: Sorry, the code was written off-the-cuff. I've moved the keyword argument to the correct location in the function definition.

Comment: ok. sorry to bother again. Now I'm receiving: `mergeiter() got multiple values for keyword argument 'key'`

Comment: @frequent: Okay, a tested version, this time. :-) Sorry again!

Comment: I just tried wrapping `key=lambda line: stringsplit(line)` in `(...)`, which will pass `key`... I assume. let's see :-)

Comment: @frequent: Apologies, noticed there was a `*` missing on the `mergeiter()` example call. Corrected that too. Multitasking and SO don't mix that well... :-)

Comment: :-)  I also added a `*` in `glob.glob('logs/*')]` which I forgot in my original code. Script is running, let's see what happens :-)