# Combing 2 python Lists and sorting by date while preserving source

Tags: python, datetime

```
import datetime
dic1 = [datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 4, 17, 48, 4), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 4, 17, 48, 4), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 4, 17, 58, 18), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 4, 17, 58, 18), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 5,
 1, 8, 13), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 5, 1, 8, 13), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 5, 1, 8, 45), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 5, 1, 8, 45), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 5, 15, 40, 54), datetime.datetime(2014
, 2, 5, 15, 40, 54), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 5, 15, 49, 41)]

dic2 = [datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 5, 15, 49, 41), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 5, 17, 43, 26), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 5, 17, 43, 26), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 5, 22, 36), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 5, 22, 36), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 6, 15, 26, 54), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 6, 15, 26, 54), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 6, 21, 19, 42),
datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 6, 21, 19, 42), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 7, 0, 9, 3), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 7, 0, 9, 3), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 7, 16, 15, 11), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 7, 16,
15, 11), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 7, 16, 33, 33)]

for i in dic1:
    print i, " source is dic1"

print "--"
for i in dic2:
    print i, " source is dic2"
```

This outputs data like this:

```
2014-02-04 17:48:04  source is dic1
2014-02-04 17:48:04  source is dic1
2014-02-04 17:58:18  source is dic1
2014-02-04 17:58:18  source is dic1
2014-02-05 01:08:13  source is dic1
2014-02-05 01:08:13  source is dic1
2014-02-05 01:08:45  source is dic1
2014-02-05 01:08:45  source is dic1
2014-02-05 15:40:54  source is dic1
2014-02-05 15:40:54  source is dic1
2014-02-05 15:49:41  source is dic1

2014-02-05 15:49:41  source is dic2
2014-02-05 17:43:26  source is dic2
2014-02-05 17:43:26  source is dic2
2014-02-05 22:36:00  source is dic2
2014-02-05 22:36:00  source is dic2
2014-02-06 15:26:54  source is dic2
2014-02-06 15:26:54  source is dic2
2014-02-06 21:19:42  source is dic2
2014-02-06 21:19:42  source is dic2
2014-02-07 00:09:03  source is dic2
2014-02-07 00:09:03  source is dic2
2014-02-07 16:15:11  source is dic2
2014-02-07 16:15:11  source is dic2
2014-02-07 16:33:33  source is dic2
```

**What I am trying to do is combine the 2 lists in chronological order while preserving the source (Like below). Any way to do this?**

```
2014-02-07 16:15:11  source is dic1 
2014-02-07 16:33:33  source is dic2
2014-02-07 18:09:03  source is dic1
2014-02-07 20:15:11  source is dic1
```

Comment: The input lists are always sorted?

Comment: I see that all values in `dic2` are greater than all values in `dic1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it is.

```
for dt, src in sorted(
        [(t,'dic1') for t in dic1] + [(t,'dic2') for t in dic2] ):
    print '{} from source {}'.format(dt, src)
```

-- output --

```
2014-02-04 17:48:04 from source dic1
2014-02-04 17:48:04 from source dic1
2014-02-04 17:58:18 from source dic1
2014-02-04 17:58:18 from source dic1
2014-02-05 01:08:13 from source dic1
2014-02-05 01:08:13 from source dic1
2014-02-05 01:08:45 from source dic1
2014-02-05 01:08:45 from source dic1
2014-02-05 15:40:54 from source dic1
2014-02-05 15:40:54 from source dic1
2014-02-05 15:49:41 from source dic1
2014-02-05 15:49:41 from source dic2
2014-02-05 17:43:26 from source dic2
2014-02-05 17:43:26 from source dic2
2014-02-05 22:36:00 from source dic2
2014-02-05 22:36:00 from source dic2
2014-02-06 15:26:54 from source dic2
2014-02-06 15:26:54 from source dic2
2014-02-06 21:19:42 from source dic2
2014-02-06 21:19:42 from source dic2
2014-02-07 00:09:03 from source dic2
2014-02-07 00:09:03 from source dic2
2014-02-07 16:15:11 from source dic2
2014-02-07 16:15:11 from source dic2
2014-02-07 16:33:33 from source dic2
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd produce tuples with `(datetime, source)` and merge the two lists; no need to use sorting if you do your merging intelligently. Here is a iterable merger I wrote for a [different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465154/sorting-text-file-by-using-python/14465236#14465236); it can be made more efficient still using `heapq` but this one is more readable:

```
import operator

def mergeiter(*iterables, **kwargs):
    """Given a set of sorted iterables, yield the next value in merged order

    Takes an optional `key` callable to compare values by.
    """
    iterables = [iter(it) for it in iterables]
    iterables = {i: [next(it), i, it] for i, it in enumerate(iterables)}
    if 'key' not in kwargs:
        key = operator.itemgetter(0)
    else:
        key = lambda item, key=kwargs['key']: key(item[0])

    while True:
        value, i, it = min(iterables.values(), key=key)
        yield value
        try:
            iterables[i][0] = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            del iterables[i]
            if not iterables:
                raise
```

You'd use it like this:

```
source1 = ((dt, 'source is dic1') for dt in dic1)
source2 = ((dt, 'source is dic2') for dt in dic2)

for dt, source in mergeiter(source1, source2):
    print dt, source
```

The `source1` and `source2` inputs are generator expressions; they only produce values as they are iterated over. By looping over `mergeiter()` values from either generator are produced, in order, with their source attached.

This is also *very* memory efficient; no copies are made of the input lists, only enough data is kept in memory to determine the next value to output.

For your sample data, this produces:

```
>>> source1 = ((dt, 'source is dic1') for dt in dic1)
>>> source2 = ((dt, 'source is dic2') for dt in dic2)
>>> for dt, source in mergeiter(source1, source2):
...     print dt, source
... 
2014-02-04 17:48:04 source is dic1
2014-02-04 17:48:04 source is dic1
2014-02-04 17:58:18 source is dic1
2014-02-04 17:58:18 source is dic1
2014-02-05 01:08:13 source is dic1
2014-02-05 01:08:13 source is dic1
2014-02-05 01:08:45 source is dic1
2014-02-05 01:08:45 source is dic1
2014-02-05 15:40:54 source is dic1
2014-02-05 15:40:54 source is dic1
2014-02-05 15:49:41 source is dic1
2014-02-05 15:49:41 source is dic2
2014-02-05 17:43:26 source is dic2
2014-02-05 17:43:26 source is dic2
2014-02-05 22:36:00 source is dic2
2014-02-05 22:36:00 source is dic2
2014-02-06 15:26:54 source is dic2
2014-02-06 15:26:54 source is dic2
2014-02-06 21:19:42 source is dic2
2014-02-06 21:19:42 source is dic2
2014-02-07 00:09:03 source is dic2
2014-02-07 00:09:03 source is dic2
2014-02-07 16:15:11 source is dic2
2014-02-07 16:15:11 source is dic2
2014-02-07 16:33:33 source is dic2
```

Unfortunately, your sample input data uses two sources that do not overlap in their timestamp ranges.

Your output sample does use sources that'd mix. Using those as input would look like:

```
>>> dic1 = [datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 7, 16, 15, 11), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 7, 18, 9, 3), datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 7, 20, 15, 11)]
>>> dic2 = [datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 7, 16, 33, 33)]
>>> source1 = ((dt, 'source is dic1') for dt in dic1)
>>> source2 = ((dt, 'source is dic2') for dt in dic2)
>>> for dt, source in mergeiter(source1, source2):
...     print dt, source
... 
2014-02-07 16:15:11 source is dic1
2014-02-07 16:33:33 source is dic2
2014-02-07 18:09:03 source is dic1
2014-02-07 20:15:11 source is dic1
```