# What is time complexity of the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

```
 def multi_merge_v1(lst_of_lsts):
      all = [e for lst in lst_of_lsts for e in lst]
      merged = []
      while all != []:
            minimum = min(all)
            merged += [minimum]
            all.remove(minimum)
      return merged
```

What is the time complexity of this code? is it O(2mn)? Because creating "all" requires mn steps and also while requires mn steps

Comment: you could use [`heapq.merge(*lst_of_lsts)`](http://docs.python.org/3.5/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge), here's a [code example that uses `merge()` to sort a text file that doesn't fit in memory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16954837/4279)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about algorithm complexity, not programming. Try [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Why would you want to *delete* the answered question? There is no migration to cs.stackexchange as I understand. And even if the migration were possible, you should [avoid migrating answered questions and don't migrate for the sake of migration](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/137096).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: There is no automatic migration path; and I did not intent for anything to be deleted, but fair enough. The barrage of questions by this user were mostly off-topic still though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: As far as I remember, most closed questions are deleted automatically after some time. Previous questions shouldn't matter unless it is a duplicate.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: No, they are only deleted if unanswered, and with a score of 0 or less. See the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thank you for the link (a [quick search](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=when+closed+question+are+deleted) does not yield it). Questions with answers *were/are/will be* deleted automatically with some exceptions even according to the set of rules enumerated in [the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/137096).

Comment: The majority of rules exempt questions with answers. The only way your answer is at jeopardy is if the question had a negative vote and the question asker account was deleted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: related: [When/Why a question with accepted answer and more answers is deleted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270586/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: than only applies when the author of the question is deleted. That is an exception to the rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `O((m*n)**2)` because `while` loop is executed `m*n` times and `min(all)`, `all.remove(minimum)` are `O(n*m)` operations.

Comment: what about creating "all" isn't it mn?

Comment: @user7777777: `O(n**2 + n) == O(n**2)` i.e., `mn` doesn't matter compared to `(mn)**2`

Comment: Doesn't "all" is  a list that doesn't have lists in it instead a one long list created of lists that were in lst_of_lsts, so why min(all) doesn't requires m+n operations?
=

Comment: @user7777777: `len(all)` is `m*n` assuming `len(lst_of_lsts) == n` and `len(sublist) == m` Look at the nested loop in the list comprehension `for e in lst` is executed for *every* list