# Sorting from a File

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I'm attempting to read values from a file and then sort them, and then rewriting the values back to the file. The file contains the following syntax for the value: `NAME, SCORE/10`. Each new value begins on a new line e.g:

```
TEST, 5/10
TEST2, 2/10
```

Currently, I have the sorting of A - Z working. However, I am having difficulty sorting via the values. Could anybody help me with sorting from Highest Num - Lowest Num? (10 - 0)

The code I have currently to read the Values is this:

```
def splitList(alist):
    a = []
    i = 0
    for i in range(alist.count("\n")):
        a = a.append(alist[:])
        i =+ 1
    return a
```

And this is what I have to sort from Highest to Lowest:

```
def sortFile(filePath, mode = "ABC"):
    if mode == "321":
        try:
            f = open(filePath, "r")
            try:
                lines = f.readlines()
                print(lines)
                lines = lines.sort(key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
                print(lines)
                f.close()
                f = open(filePath, "w")
                f.writelines(lines)
            finally:
                f.close()
        except IOError:
            pass
        return True
```

Comment: But what is you 'difficulty'? Does the program sort anything, but results are incorrect? Does it drop some data or duplicates it? Does it run at all?

Comment: @CiaPan the problem is this (High - Low) `f.writelines(lines)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

Comment: So the problem is the `lines` object returned from `sort()` is not proper. But didn't `print()` complain about it earlier? Could you add example - what data you try to sort, what was the printout of the data before and after `sort()`?

Comment: @CiaPan It returns all the lines of the text file as a list seperated by the commas but, after the sort, it then returns `none`

Comment: ...and now you can ask the right question: "what's wrong with my call to `sort()` and how can I correct it".

Answer (score 0):

Define sorting criteria however you like:

```
def key_az_reverse_numeric(line):
    alpha, sep, score10 = line.partition(',')
    score10 = score10.strip()
    if sep and score10.endswith('/10'): 
       try:
           return alpha.strip(), -int(score10[:-len('/10')])
       except ValueError:
           pass
    return '', float('-inf') # default
```

And use it to sort the file:

```
def sort_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        lines = file.readlines() # assume the last line has newline
    lines.sort(key=key_az_reverse_numeric)
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        file.writelines(lines)
```

To sort a large file that do not fit in memory, you could [sort the file in small batches and merge the sorted results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16954837/4279).

To find out what `line.partition(',')` means you could search google using keywords: `python partition`. The first result points to the Python docs for `str.partition` method. `line` is a string so it looks like what we need. [Click the link.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition)

Comment: Could you please explain what the line `alpha, sep, score10 = line.partition(',')` means please? I understand that you're splitting the string, but why do you need 3 variables to carry this value?

Comment: @artman41: I've added instructions how to find out what is `line.partition()`.

Comment: ah, makes a lot more sense now - need 3 variables, one for each part of the tuple

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode, do not attempt to copy paste. Write a function that strips the string values for sorting functions inside the sorting method, then return which one is superior.

```
def sort(line1, line2) {
  //strip the lines for their values, then compare and return value
  returns 1 if line1 > line2, -1 if line1 < line2, 0 if line1 == line2
}

for(int i = 0; i < arraylength, i++) {
 line1 = array[i];
 line2 = array[i+1];
 placeholderline = null;
 int ordering = sort(line1, line2);
 if(ordering = 1) {
  placeholderline = line2;
  array[i+1] = line1;
  array[i] = line2;
 }
```

//ordering is already ok if they are equal or 1 is smaller than 2 depending on ascending/descending

Does this help? I am not a python expert so it's hard for me to provide python specific answers but the principle is the same.