# Sorting a text file alphabetically (Python)

Tags: python, sorting

I would like to sort the file 'shopping.txt' in alphabetical order

```
shopping = open('shopping.txt')
line=shopping.readline()
while len(line)!=0:
    print(line, end ='')
    line=shopping.readline()
#for eachline in myFile:
#    print(eachline)
shopping.close()
```

Answer (score 59):

Just to show something different instead of doing this in python, you can do this from a command line in Unix systems:

```
sort shopping.txt -o shopping.txt
```

and your file is sorted. Of course if you really want python for this: solution proposed by a lot of other people with reading file and sorting works fine

Comment: Its better than writing scripts from scratch

Answer (score 29):

An easy way to do this is using the `sort()` or `sorted()` functions.

```
lines = shopping.readlines()
lines.sort()
```

Alternatively:

```
lines = sorted(shopping.readlines())
```

The disadvantage is that you have to read the whole file into memory, though. If that's not a problem, you can use this simple code.

Answer (score 17):

Use `sorted` function.

```
with open('shopping.txt', 'r') as r:
    for line in sorted(r):
        print(line, end='')
```

Comment: Could you please let me know whether this would take all lines in memory. How would this work. Does this read input lazily.

Comment: @AkshayHazari: `sorted()` loads all lines in memory. To avoid loading all the lines, you could call the external `sort` command or [implement it in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16954837/4279)

Comment: How might this replace the existing file?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) you can use:

```py
from pathlib import Path

file = Path("shopping.txt")
print(sorted(file.read_text().split("\n")))
```

Or if you want to sort the file on disk

```py
from pathlib import Path

file = Path("shopping.txt")
file.write_text(
    "\n".join(
        sorted(
            file.read_text().split("\n")
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
shopping = open('shopping.txt')
lines = shopping.readlines()
lines.sort()
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Comment: Need to close opened file after this or use `with` statement as external context manager

Answer (score 0):

This code reads the file, sorts the lines and writes it back to the file system, without any lib (not even standard lib except the built-in functions). The other answers don't output the results or use any libs for output (pathlib, etc.), or they only print it to the command line.

```
input_file = "input.txt"
output_file = "output.txt"
with open(input_file) as f:
    with open(output_file, "w") as o:
        o.write("\n".join(sorted(f.read().splitlines())))
```

You can also put this inside a function if you have to rename multiple files:

```
def sort_file(input_file, output_file):
    with open(input_file) as f:
        with open(output_file, "w") as o:
            o.write("\n".join(sorted(f.read().splitlines())))

sort_file("input.txt", "output.txt")
```