# How to sort an output file based on second parameter?

Tags: python-3.x, string, sorting, output, text-files

I am trying to sort a result I write into an output file after a certain character ':' by the integer after the character.

First, I tried using sort function but it did not work as it was not a list. I also tried to convert everything to string list and tried to sort accordingly but do not think it’s the most efficient way to go.

**NOTE:** output file lines are all strings

```
**Current written output in output_file1.txt:**
hi: 011
hello: 000
hero: 001
You are done!

**Expected written output in output_file1.txt:**
hello: 000
hero: 001
hi: 011
You are done!
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can't sort the file in place with python. You will need to put the entire file into memory to sort it or you can sort it using a `unix` shell. [Sorting a text file alphabetically (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123125/sorting-a-text-file-alphabetically-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(filepath) as file:
    r = file.readlines()

#splits based on ":" and then sort using the second value ie binary numbers
s = sorted([line.split(":") for line in r[1:-1]], key=lambda x: int(x[1]))

s.insert(0,r[0])
s.append(r[-1])

#Write 's' into File
```

Answer (score 0):

I would the insert the lines in order from the very beginning, you can do that efficiently using binary search.

***Q***: How to compare the current number in the current line with your old file.

***Answer***:

**Case 1:** If the maximum number of lines is 111, (in your example you start with 001, I assume you padded with zeros to show how many digits you expect per number) or you now the max number of lines, you can pad with a sufficient number of zeros, then all you have to do is compare you current number with the current last three entries in your line (line[-3:]).

**Case 2: You don't know the number of digits:**

**Sol 2.1:** You can try storing a file for words and a file for numbers, and update them in parallel, this will save you from the overhead of Sol 2.2.

**Sol 2.2:** Split the line by delimiter ':' and get the number (don't forget that you have a space after the delimiter).

That is what I could come up with for now!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, there is no way to sort a file in place.

Regarding your second question, you can use `list.sort(key=sort_key)`. This allows you to supply a method which is applied to every element in your list when comparing the elements for sorting.

In your case you can define a simple function which extracts the last three characters and sort them alphabetically:

```
def num_sort(x):
   return x[-3:]
your_list.sort(key=num_sort)
```