# How should I use the sort command using python?

Tags: python, sorting, command, subprocess

I have a bunch of different text files, and am trying to sort the texts into one file. I am using python's subprocess, and I wrote the following code

```
command_line = "sort -m 1.txt 2.txt > a.txt"
args = shlex.split(command_line)
subprocess.call(args)
```

and the subprocess.call(args) returned 2 as a result, and nothing was written in a.txt. Anything wrong with my code?

Comment: unrelated: `sort -m` does not sort the files. It merges *already  sorted* files.

Comment: See also [Sorting text file by using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14465154/4279)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the shell redirection operator `>` in your command line, you have to pass `shell=True` to `subprocess.call`. Otherwise, '>' and 'a.txt' are passed as command line arguments to `sort`. With `shell=True`, the command line is passed to and interpreted by an actual shell, and you should therefore not `shlex.split` it. It may be easier to use `os.system` instead of `subprocess.call`, which uses a shell by default.

Comment: "have to" is a bit strong. `call('sort -m 1.txt 2.txt'.split(), stdout=open('a.out', 'w'))` works without `shell=True`. See answers to the duplicate question

Comment: One "has to" if one wants to use an actual shell command line. I will clarify the answer.